# Pandas Ydata-profling is taking so long for a particular columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need your help troubleshooting this
Pandas Ydata-profling is taking so long for particular columns.
These columns are the Unique ID of the rows.
How can I see what is happening here?

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
profile = ProfileReport(df , title="XXX XXX XX")
profile.to_file("xxx_xxx_xxx.html")
```

This the only code I wrote .